# Issue getting entire element from mongo using golang bson instead only child element is being returned

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I am working on a mongo query in golang using mgo to query a child element to return the entire element

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b64a0d3931653c36bcaf0b5"),
    "quantity" : 2,
    "product" : "ABC",   
    "children" : [ 
        {           
            "isBlocked" : true,
            "blockedMessage" : "Error occurred: TRACEID",
            "serialNo" : "abc123",
            "token" : "foo456",            
        }
    ]
}
```

The query I am using in below
   bson.M{"_id": 0, "children": bson.M{"$elemMatch": {serialNo: 'abc123'}}}

```
Find(MongoSpec{Selector: bson.M{}, Query: bson.M{"_id": 0, "children": bson.M{"$elemMatch": fields}}})
```

Below is the find function

```
    documents := []interface{}{}
        s := spec.(MongoSpec).Selector
        q := spec.(MongoSpec).Query
        query := session.
            DB(repo.Config.DatabaseName).
            C(repo.CollectionName).
            Find(s)

        if q != nil {
            query = query.Select(q)
        }

        err := query.All(&documents)
```

MongoSpec struct

```
  type MongoSpec struct {
        Selector interface{}
        Query    interface{}
    }
```

The above query works fine but returns only children element as below

```
"children" : [ 
            {           
                "isBlocked" : true,
                "blockedMessage" : "Error occurred: TRACEID",
                "serialNo" : "abc123",
                "token" : "foo456",            
            }
        ]
```

I am not getting what is wrong with the query.

Comment: Have you tried your query in mongo CLI (or some other mongo tool) directly? If you get the same result, then this is purely a mongodb question, not a Go question. If this is actually a Go issue though, we'll need to see the relevant Go code.

Comment: Please add more of your Go code. I think I know the issue but want to verify by seeing your Go code before I answer.

Comment: The Go code fragment you posted does not justify the result you get. If you want help, you need to post more of your code, aim for a [mcve]. As it is now, this question is off topic.

Comment: @Adrian Added more go code as I do not have any issues with querying on mongo CLI

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin added more go code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$elemMatch` exists as both a **[query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch)** and a **[projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).** A query is used to actually filter **which documents** are returned, and a projection determines **which part of the documents returned** are shown. To reiterate: Projection doesn't filter which documents are returned, it limits which values per document are returned (similar to the `SELECT` part of SQL).

mgo's `Find` function is the query, and `Select` is the projection. Therefore, you want your final code to look closer to this:

```
c.Find(
    bson.M{
        "children": bson.M{
            "$elemMatch": bson.M{serialNo: "abc123"},
        },
    },
).Select(
    bson.M{
        "_id": 0,
    },
)
```

With how you have your code set up, this is how it would look.

```
Find(
    MongoSpec{
        Selector: bson.M{"children": bson.M{"$elemMatch": fields}},
        Query: bson.M{"_id": 0},
    },
)
```

However, I'd strongly advise you rename the fields in `MongoSpec` (dropping it and the Find function altogether might not be a bad idea, too). You use `Query` as your projection (the `.Select()` function) and you use `Selector` as your query (`.Find()`). That may be why you made this mistake in the first place.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks and Yes you are right. I will make changes as suggested. Thank ou!

Comment: @DoIt no problem! :) See the last paragraph I just added... I think you may have accidentally swapped the names of the Selector and Query fields in `MongoSpec`... fixing that will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Sure. My earlier comment was in response to the last paragraph

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin could you please modify the projection phrase to `Projection doesn't filter which documents are returned, it limits which values per document that are returned`. Projection happens in the server not just how it's shown, projection can help reduce network bandwidth and achieve covered query state. Thanks